# Revision log not showing tags added that no longer exist

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, revisions-list

[This question's revision log](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/15752/revisions) suggests that only a tag (in this case, a game's German name) was removed, while [in reality](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15752/issues-with-running-diggles-the-myth-of-fenris-wiggles-on-windows-7#comment-45421) it was replaced by another one (here, the English name) which has vanished due to this question being the only one using it.

For the sake of consistency, either the other tag (also unused) should also vanish from the history, or, better, the no longer existing new tag should show up in the history as well, maybe together with a Community owned edit removing the tag -faking history was never a good idea to start with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the issue; the current tag-burnination works by:

- for posts currently tagged [foo](/questions/tagged/foo)

  - remove [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) from their history
  - remove [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) from the actual post
- remove the [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) tag

what it *doesn't* currently consider is posts **previously** tagged [foo](/questions/tagged/foo).

Given the way the excising of the tag works, your "or better" approach isn't really a viable option. I've investigated the other aspect of consistency here, and *at present* that would be prohibitively expensive on some sites. To do this *efficiently*, we would need to add an unwieldy amount of additional storage, that would *only* support this fairly rare scenario.

Perhaps what *is* feasible is that we .... lie. Essentially, when displaying the history, we could suppress all trace of tags which we know do not exist any more - i.e. because [wiggles](/questions/tagged/wiggles) is now dead we simply don't show it on that view. This seems to achieve something like the desired perception of consistency ;p And indeed, it is no *less* confusing than the fact that we don't the [diggles](/questions/tagged/diggles).

Thoughts? Of course, if we do that, several revisions could look like no-ops; for example, Mana would have changed it from

[pc](/questions/tagged/pc) [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7) [technical-support](/questions/tagged/technical-support)

to

[pc](/questions/tagged/pc) [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7) [technical-support](/questions/tagged/technical-support)

I wonder... is it really worth changing it?

Comment: well I guess if not too much work is involved it would be nice since currently history looks like a perfectly reasonable tag was removed. but yes, due to the rarity of this issue, your time is probably best spent otherwise...